# How to make one column data to rows in excel (google sheet)

Tags: google-sheets

want to know how to preprocessing data form in excel.

[image]

How do I easily make this left(one column data) to right(pretty well structured dataframe) transform via excel(or google sheet)?
It's difficult to do manual work because of the data size.

Comment: Your post (and thus your goal) is unclear. We don't see any range information. And it's unclear whether you want the first three rows' data (i.e., 1, 2, 3) to be in three separate columns or all concatenated into one cell. The most efficient way to make everything clear is to share a link to a sample spreadsheet with *realistic* data *and* your hand-entered expected results for a limited set of that data.

Comment: thank you for your feedback Erik. I uploaded my google sheet screenshot.

Comment: Jenny, an image is somewhat helpful (though what you show here does not match your originally posted goal of grouping every three elements; here you show grouping every four elements). However, this does not look like it represents *realistic* data. Are you saying that that, in your real spreadsheet, your data is all numerical, that the first numerical element is in cell A1, that this list of numerical data is *all there is* in that sheet at the start, that you want it grouped every four (instead of every three), and that you want the results to appear in the same sheet as the original data?

Comment: You can see by the above questions I needed to ask why sharing a link to the *actual* spreadsheet (or to a copy of it with only, say, the first 20 elements left in it) is necessary, rather than just an image. Everything matters. And your image does not appear to show that accurately: exact range where the original data is; *how* that data got into the sheet, (e.g., copy/paste, internal formula, external formula like one of the IMPORT formulas, etc.), what the exact data types are per line, where the output should go, what your international locale is and more. It all matters.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(QUERY(A1:A10, "skipping 3", )&
            QUERY(A2:A10, "skipping 3", )&
            QUERY(A3:A10, "skipping 3", )))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See my important additional comments to your original post.

Those comments notwithstanding, if your spreadsheet is set up *exactly* as shown in your image, *and* if your data types for the final layout will be the same per column, *and* if there are no gaps in your data (i.e., the data cycles ***every*** four rows without exception), *and* if your international locale is one that uses a comma to separate formula parameters... then delete everything shown in your image for Cols D, E, F and G and then place the following formula in D2:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({A:A,{A2:A;""},{A3:A;"";""},{A4:A;"";"";""}},"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null SKIPPING 4"))`

The four sub-arrays `{ __,{__},{__},{__} }` that form the `QUERY` have null pseudo-rows added to the end of each except the first (i.e. adding 0, 1, 2 and 3 null rows respectively), in order to keep the four array lengths parallel despite their having different starting points.